# Use variable to get property value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I want be able to get values from my database using a variable, the last line is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
class Data(db.Model):
  property = db.StringProperty()

data = Data(property = 'value')
data.put()

query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Data")

myvar = 'property'

for line in query:
  line[myvar]
```

Comment: use getattr(object, name) : getattr(line, myvar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you voscausa,

```
class Data(db.Model):
  property = db.StringProperty()

data = Data(property = 'value')
data.put()

query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Data")

myvar = 'property'

for line in query:
  getattr(line, myvar)
```